# How to delete data after updating the app

Tags: java, android

How to clean the Data after updating the app so that this code is executed only once after the update **and that the Data is 0kb**? Thanks

```
public void clearApplicationData() {
    File cache = getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return dir.delete();
}
```

Comment: Hey Misionar, what have you tried?

Comment: I added the code in the message.

Comment: put a shared preference entry with your version current version in your application's on create method if the version is changed or not. And if it does not, delete all your caches file.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have version `1.0` installed.

**Save the version code** in the `sharedPreferences` and *compare app version code with the saved one every time app starts*.

If you *updat*e the app, so you have `1.1` and when you start you'll see that the saved one is `1.0` and now it's `1.1`. So it means you need to clear app data using your clear function.

Something like this:

```
fun saveVersion() {
    val currentVersion = context.packageManager
                .getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0)
                .run {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                        longVersionCode
                    } else {
                        versionCode.toLong()
                    }
                }
    val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    sharedPreferences.edit().putLong("versionCode", currentVersion).apply()
 }

 fun getSavedVersion(): Long {
     val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
     return sharedPreferences.getLong("versionCode", -1L)
 }
```

and on app's MainActivity `onCreate()`:

```
if (getSavedVersion() == -1L) {
   saveVersion()
} else {
   if (currentVersion > getVersion()) {
       // Then you must clear data
       clearApplicationData()
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the most realistic solution!!! Can you give me the complete code, please?

Comment: Actually, this is the code. Simply add the codes in your `MainActivity` or whatever activity your launcher is. The language is **Kotlin**. Feel free to vote and accept the question if it helped you.